# Why is there an "Implicit any return type" error here?

Tags: typescript

I would expect the following code to successfully be type-checked :

```js
class MyClass<T extends object, P extends string = string> {
    method(thing: Thing) {
        return thing.method(this);
    }
}

declare class Thing {
    method(entity: MyClass<any>): void;
}
```

Yet `method` from `MyClass` is underlined in red and it reads :

```
(method) MyClass<T extends object, P extends string = string>.method(thing: Thing): any
'method' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.(7023)
```

**[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVaBTAHgFywDsATGAewCMArLYPAGmgAVt8jToI8AnAS0IDm0ALyce-AQD5oAbwBQ0RdAC2WPAAsyxABQaJALmjp1EgJSyFSq9zUBXboWh7BAOlUatukxFMBuS4oAvnLBcsS04DbQoJAwxhIWVu6aOkR4vHjwhgjIsahghPCSpoYAbmS8xP6BQA)**

If that's a typescript bug, I will post it on their github issue tracker, but I would first like to hear your insight. Thank you.

Comment: Feels like [microsoft/TypeScript#38724](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38724) and/or [microsoft/TypeScript#35546](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35546); there is a circularity, but it's surprising that the circularity should matter, as classes dealing with `this` often have such circularities without complaint.

Comment: @jcalz I fail to see the circularity since `Thing.prototype.method`'s return type isn't influence by `MyClass` at all. Could you explain please ?

Comment: Before it even gets to check `thing.method(this)`'s return type, it needs to make sure it's a valid call (it has to resolve the call signature).  And to make sure of that, it tries to assign `this` to `MyClass<any>`. To check that, it needs to make sure that, among other things, `this.method()`'s return type is compatible with `MyClass<any>.method()`'s return type, and it gets unhappy because it hasn't determined that yet.

Comment: @jcalz I see, thanks !

Comment: The analysis that says "there's only one call signature for `thing.method()` so I can figure out its return type without even checking the parameters first" is not something the compiler apparently does.

Comment: I can write this up as an answer I guess, but I wish I had something better to say about why this doesn't happen *all the time*.  Like, it's easy-ish to find a circularity, but it's harder to understand why minor changes in that code make the error go away.  As I said, every time you use `this` inside a class, it's circular.  It likely comes down to specific details of the type inference and unification algorithm, which I don't really know.

Comment: @jcalz I suggest you write the answer anyway, I learned something that might profit others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you if you want to file an issue in GitHub, but I suspect it would be closed as either a design limitation or working as intended.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#38724](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38724) and [microsoft/TypeScript#35546](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35546) for similar issues... or [search for "directly or indirectly" in the issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/search?q=%22directly+or+indirectly%22&type=issues).   Generally speaking, when the compiler warns about such a circularity, it's because the type inference algorithm would result in an infinite regress if it did not bail out.  Meaning that there really is a circularity.  Whether or not a human being of moderate intelligence would be able to reason about it without getting caught in the same loop [is not really relevant](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42529#issuecomment-769313907):

> This really is a circularity; the fact that we can higher-order-reason our way out of it doesn't make it not a circularity. The core checking algorithm doesn't have mechanisms in place that would allow this to be resolved.

---

For your example, I'm taking my cue from microsoft/TypeScript#38724 and [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38724#issuecomment-642934795):

> This is still a circularity; to determine if the type assertion from `Object.assign(nation, this)` to `Nation` is valid, TS has to determine the type of `this`, which depends on the return type of `clone`.

Here's my guess as to what the problem is for you.

- The compiler needs to infer the return type of `MyClass<T>.method(thing: Thing)`.
- To do this, it needs to know what `thing.method(this)` returns.
- To do this, it needs to resolve the call signature for `thing.method()` for the parameter `this`.
- To do this, it looks at the first and only call signature for `Thing.method()`, and sees that the parameter is of type `MyClass<any>`, so it needs to see if `this` is assignable to `MyClass<any>`.
- To do this, it needs to check `this.method()`'s return type is assignable to `MyClass<any>.method()`'s return type.
- To do this, it needs to know `MyClass<T>.method()`'s return type.

That's a circularity, and the compiler is unhappy.  Note that this is just a guess on my part; someone with more actual compiler knowledge might be able to amend that if I got any steps wrong. The important part to note is that, no matter how obvious it might be to us that `thing.method(this)`'s return type is `void` regardless of whether `this` is an appropriate parameter, the compiler cannot simply "see" things like this.  Its algorithm hits a circularity.

---

The thing that really makes me uneasy about this sort of answer is that it implies that *whenever* you use `this` inside a class and you don't annotate everything, the compiler should complain about circularities. The `this` type is inherently circular.  But of course this doesn't happen; most of the time the compiler happily "overlooks" such circularities.  And you can make seemingly irrelevant changes to your code to make the error disappear as if my magic:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    method(thing: Thing) { // no error now
        const ret = thing.method(this);
        return ret; 
    }
}
```

Presumably it comes down to the exact order of operations in the type inference algorithm, which was undoubtedly designed to support common use cases.  So it's always possible that if you could articulate a good reason why your use case is compelling, you might be able to file an issue as a suggestion and not have it immediately closed as a limitation.  But even so, I doubt it's compelling enough to have anyone address it.  Especially because it is easy to work around with a type annotation:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    method(thing: Thing): void { // annotate
        return thing.method(this);
    }
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhEATJBvAUDpBS8ANiFFEgLICeAwqeQDwAqAfNvoV5AC4AWAe3QAKfgEtgAcwBcSZnwmSAlBy5rCAJwg8ArhuBJxUgHS9BI8VCUBuTuoC+dpI6foIJEFqIMK8xavUkMyFhCGAeMR5qWRp6MihGEGBqViVZADcBMXRbLhcXUEhYBGQAdQgxDUxcLg9yKjofFnYawOCLBSlZPykVVsDCeAFgKB4kLTGAXkNOyVNtc1EFK1yBzW09AwnVhycXLjcPLzrfWYD1dtDwyOiGuKYklLSkTOyd5xwC8Gg4RCRSgQaADWngEOmA1TwtR8dyabHOakuRhkclmz1ekLW610+hminm-BClhsTjyeyhhEOpGOMJ6kgR3AWITCESiMUa8USyVSGSyOXJnxwQA)